# Swagger Sails JS in production

Tags: sails.js, swagger, swagger-ui, rspec-api-documentation

I want to only have swagger in development environment but I want to disable this link or disable swagger when deploy on production. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the [NPM](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install) docs for install

"With the --production flag (or when the NODE_ENV environment variable is set to production), npm will not install modules listed in devDependencies."

"The --only={prod[uction]|dev[elopment]} argument will cause either only devDependencies or only non-devDependencies to be installed regardless of the NODE_ENV."

to install package  for dev only :-

```
npm install swagger --only=dev
```

Comment: well, you're save me. Thanks you